# Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter

Tags: ios, xcode, testing

exeute

```
xcrun xccov view --archive --file #{file_path} #{xcresult_path} > result.txt
```

console log:

```
2020-09-17 15:33:01.346 xccov[80302:9272810] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEFoundation.IDEResultKitSerializationConverter
2020-09-17 15:33:01.396 xccov[80302:9272810] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-17198/DVTFoundation/DocumentLocations/DVTDocumentLocation.m:277
Details: DVTDocumentLocation: Failed to find requested class with name Xcode3ProjectDocumentLocation (or isn't a subclass of DVTDocumentLocation). Falling back to DVTDocumentLocation.
Object:  <DVTDocumentLocation>
Method:  +deserializedDocumentLocationForClassName:stringRepresentation:error:
Thread:  <NSThread: 0x7fd8d7e177b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2020-09-17 15:33:01.396 xccov[80302:9272810] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-17198/DVTFoundation/DocumentLocations/DVTDocumentLocation.m:277
Details: DVTDocumentLocation: Failed to find requested class with name Xcode3ProjectDocumentLocation (or isn't a subclass of DVTDocumentLocation). Falling back to DVTDocumentLocation

......
```

Although the result is correct, but how to reslove these warnings?

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

this fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

If you are getting the invalid directory then try to install the command-line tool

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, it actually made it worse but breaking all command line tools, not just `xccov`

Comment: I did not work for me too and made it worse. I am using Xcode 15.0.1